# What does "from" stand for in a pending transaction on ethereum?

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions

As you may see on this link of pending transactions https://etherscan.io/txsPending

You may see that there is a list of pending transactions. If you select one of them you will see the following

[image]

Somehow, I thought that the 'from' should not be here based on my reading of "Mastering Ethereum
Building Smart Contracts and DApps" where it says clearly that

> there is no “from” data in the address identifying the originator EOA. That is because the EOA’s public key can be derived from the v,r,s components of the ECDSA signature.

I thought that the transaction is transmitted through the network with RLP-encoding but it seems I am mistaken and there is a Transaction Hash which (please correct me if I am mistaken) is the keecak-256 hash of the RLP-encoded tx. Is this how the contract is transmitted through the network?

I understand that the data are stored in ethereum within the block as the Merkle trie root as described [here](https://hackernoon.com/getting-deep-into-ethereum-how-data-is-stored-in-ethereum-e3f669d96033).

If you please help me understand this as I am really struggling to get my head around this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The from here is actually derived from the signature of the sender. It is important to know that the public key is extracted from the signature. Furthermore from the signature you can extract the contact address or the Sender address.

Although the transaction is propagated without the from field. This field can be found. The transaction is propagated through the RLP encoded serialization.

Answer (score 0):

From is the EOA (natural account) that originally created the Ethereum transaction and send it to its first destination that can another EOA or a smart contract. As the text you quoted says, it is a derived property of a public key that signed the transaction. EtherScan, JSON-RPC and other programming libraries conveniently unpack it for you (probably stored also in geth internal database).

For other questions, I suggest you open a separate questions on Ethereum StackExchange, as multiquestion questions and difficult to answer and discuss.

Comment: The concepts are related, how is the transaction spread across the platform. So when is RLP-encoded occurs, after a signature?

Comment: If you have another question I suggest you open a new question with this title and more information.

Comment: Thanks for the help I already post it but do you know with certainty the answer to my question? It is available here but no one answered it till now. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109278/are-the-tx-signed-then-rlp-encoded-then-hashed-to-be-transmitted-to-the-blockcha